# Evaluating $\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{2 \pi z}}{(z+i)^3}dz$ by using the Cauchy Integration Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve:
$\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{2 \pi z}}{(z+i)^3}dz$, $\gamma(t)=2e^{it}, t \in [0,2 \pi]$ by using the Cauchy Integration Formula.

My Calculations:

I did define $f(z):=z\frac{e^{2 \pi z}}{(z+i)^3}$, this way I can write the Integral as
$\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-0}dz$ which equals $2 \pi i f(0)=0$

Question: Is my calculation correct?

Comment: It is not correct because $f$ is not analytic in $\{|z|<2\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac {e^{2\pi z}} {(z+i)^{3}}=\frac {e^{2\pi (z+i)}} {(z+i)^{3}}$ and expanding the exponential we see that the coefficient of $\frac  1 {z+i}$ is $\frac {(2\pi)^{2}} {2!}$. This the residue at $-i$ and so the value of the integral is $2\pi i \frac {(2\pi)^{2}} {2!}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z) := \mathrm{e}^{2\pi z}$.
Using Cauchy integral formula
$$f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z - a)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d} z,$$
we have
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{2\pi z}}{(z + \mathrm{i})^{3}}\,\mathrm{d} z
= \frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}}{2!}f^{(2)}(-\mathrm{i}) = 4\pi^3 \mathrm{i}.$$